# Trying to implement Hive storage for todo app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement Hive local storage into my todo test app. However, I am really struggling with this. I dont really understand how to do it despite watching and reading lots of tutorials. Is anyone able to look at the code and tell me WHY and where the hive code will go. I think for adding and updating new todos, it will go into the onsubmitted form, and for removing, it will go into the perhaps the deleteTasks for where you delete. But not really sure how.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
//import 'package:testy/page2.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
            child: const TodoApp(),
          );
        },
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow, fontFamily: "Whovetica"),
    ),
  );
}

class Todo {
  final String text;
  final bool checked;
  int priority;
  static int _tasknumber = 0;
  final int key;
//TODO: UNDERSTAND THIS
  Todo({
    required this.text,
    required this.checked,
    required this.priority,
  }) : key = _tasknumber++;
}

class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}

class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();
  List<Todo> data = [];
  int? _radioValue = 1;
  bool isEditing = false;
  int editingIndex =
      -1; // Initialize as -1 to indicate no active edit initially.
  bool isContainerVisible = false;
  bool settingsVisibility = false;

  final FocusNode _textFocus = FocusNode();
  void dispose() {
    _textFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textFocus.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isContainerVisible = _textFocus.hasFocus;
      });
    });
  }

//clear completed tasks
  void deleteComplete() {
    List<Todo> completedTasks = data.where((todo) => todo.checked).toList();
    setState(() {
      data.removeWhere((todo) => todo.checked);
    });

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('${completedTasks.length} completed tasks deleted'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              // Re-insert the completed tasks
              data.insertAll(0, completedTasks);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//Untick all tasks
  void untickAll() {
    // Create a copy of the tasks before unticking them.
    List<Todo> tasksBeforeUntick = List.from(data);

    setState(() {
      for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        if (data[index].checked) {
          data[index] = Todo(
            text: data[index].text,
            checked: false, // Untick the task
            priority: data[index].priority,
          );
        }
      }
    });

    // Show a Snackbar with an "Undo" option.
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('All completed tasks unticked'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            // Restore the tasks to their previous state.
            setState(() {
              data = List.from(tasksBeforeUntick);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//undo deleted tasks
  void deleteTasks(int index, Todo itemToDelete) {
    setState(() {
      data.removeAt(index);
    });

    // Show a SnackBar with an "Undo" action.
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Task deleted'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              data.insert(index, itemToDelete);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    data.sort((a, b) {
      if (a.checked == b.checked) {
        // If checked status is the same, sort by priority
        if (a.priority == b.priority) {
          return 0; // Same priority
        } else if (a.priority < b.priority) {
          return -1; // Sort by ascending priority
        } else {
          return 1; // Sort by descending priority
        }
      } else if (a.checked) {
        return 1; // Move completed tasks to the bottom
      } else {
        return -1; // Keep incomplete tasks at the top
      }
    });

    priorityLabel(int priority) {
      if (priority == 1) {
        return 'High';
      } else if (priority == 2) {
        return 'Medium';
      } else {
        return 'Low';
      }
    }

    Color tileColor(Todo todo) {
      if (todo.checked) {
        // If the task is checked, use a grey color.
        return Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2);
      } else {
        // If the task is not checked, determine the color based on priority.
        if (todo.priority == 1) {
          return Colors.red[300] ?? Colors.red; // High priority
        } else if (todo.priority == 2) {
          return Colors.orange[300] ?? Colors.yellow; // Medium priority
        } else {
          return Colors.yellow[300] ?? Colors.green; // Low priority
        }
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("To Do List"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: settingsVisibility
                ? Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up_outlined, color: Colors.yellow[50])
                : Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down_outlined,
                    color: Colors.yellow[700]),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                settingsVisibility = !settingsVisibility;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: settingsVisibility,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 7, 0, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.yellow[700],
                      onPressed: () {
                        untickAll();
                        setState(() {
                          settingsVisibility = !settingsVisibility;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.check_box_outlined),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.yellow[700],
                      onPressed: () {
                        deleteComplete();
                        setState(() {
                          settingsVisibility = !settingsVisibility;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete_sweep),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            //
            // LIST STARTS
            //
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 0),
              child: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
                closeWhenOpened: true,
                closeWhenTapped: true,
                child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                  reverse: false,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                        newIndex -= 1;
                      }
                      final Todo item = data.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      data.insert(newIndex, item);
                    });
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (data.isEmpty) {
                      // Handle the case when the list is empty
                      return const ListTile(
                        title: Text("No tasks to display"),
                      );
                    } else {
                      //
                      //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
                      //
                      return Container(
                        key: ValueKey(data[index].key),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Slidable(
                              closeOnScroll: true,
                              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                                motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                                children: [
                                  SlidableAction(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                    icon: Icons.edit,
                                    //label: 'Edit',
                                    onPressed: (context) => {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isEditing = true;
                                        editingIndex = index;
                                        _textyController.text =
                                            data[index].text;
                                        _radioValue = data[index].priority;
                                        _textFocus.requestFocus();
                                      }),
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SlidableAction(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        Colors.red[400] ?? Colors.red,
                                    icon: Icons.delete_forever,
                                    //label: 'Delete',
                                    onPressed: (context) => {
                                      setState(() {
                                        if (isEditing &&
                                            editingIndex >= 0 &&
                                            editingIndex < data.length) {
                                          isEditing = false;
                                          _textyController.text = '';
                                          _radioValue = 1;
                                          Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                                        }
                                        deleteTasks(index, data[index]);
                                      }),
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  color: tileColor(data[index]),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  //
                                  //LIST TILE STARTS
                                  //
                                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                                    activeColor: Colors.black,
                                    controlAffinity:
                                        ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                    title: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(
                                            data[index].text,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: data[index].checked
                                                    ? Colors.grey
                                                        .withOpacity(0.6)
                                                    : Colors.black,
                                                decoration: data[index].checked
                                                    ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                                    : TextDecoration.none),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          data[index].checked
                                              ? ''
                                              : '${index + 1}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                              fontSize: 21,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                        priorityLabel((data[index].priority))),
                                    value: data[index].checked,
                                    onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        data[index] = Todo(
                                          text: data[index].text,
                                          checked: newCheckedValue ?? false,
                                          priority: data[index].priority,
                                        );
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Visibility(
                  visible: isContainerVisible,
                  child: Container(
                    // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    //   border: Border(
                    //     top: BorderSide(
                    //         width: 1.0, color: Colors.black), // Top border
                    //     left: BorderSide(
                    //         width: 1.0, color: Colors.black), // Left border
                    //     right: BorderSide(
                    //         width: 1.0, color: Colors.black), // Right border
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Radio(
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: isEditing
                                    ? data[editingIndex].priority
                                    : _radioValue,
                                onChanged: (changedRadio) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isEditing) {
                                      data[editingIndex].priority =
                                          changedRadio ?? 1;
                                    } else {
                                      _radioValue = changedRadio;
                                    }
                                    _textFocus.requestFocus();
                                  });
                                },
                                fillColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                              ),
                              //Text('High'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Radio(
                                value: 2,
                                groupValue: isEditing
                                    ? data[editingIndex].priority
                                    : _radioValue,
                                onChanged: (changedRadio) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isEditing) {
                                      data[editingIndex].priority =
                                          changedRadio ?? 2;
                                    } else {
                                      _radioValue = changedRadio;
                                    }
                                    _textFocus.requestFocus();
                                  });
                                },
                                fillColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
                              ),
                              //Text('Medium'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Radio(
                                value: 3,
                                groupValue: isEditing
                                    ? data[editingIndex].priority
                                    : _radioValue,
                                onChanged: (changedRadio) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isEditing) {
                                      data[editingIndex].priority =
                                          changedRadio ?? 3;
                                    } else {
                                      _radioValue = changedRadio;
                                    }
                                    _textFocus.requestFocus();
                                  });
                                },
                                fillColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow),
                              ),
                              //Text('Low'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: _textFocus,
                    controller: isEditing
                        ? TextEditingController(text: data[editingIndex].text)
                        : _textyController,
                    onSubmitted: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (isEditing) {
                          data[editingIndex] = Todo(
                            text: value,
                            checked: data[editingIndex].checked,
                            priority: data[editingIndex].priority,
                          );
                          isEditing = false;
                        } else {
                          data.insert(
                              0,
                              Todo(
                                text: value,
                                checked: false,
                                priority: _radioValue ?? 0,
                              ));
                        }
                        _textyController.clear();
                        _textFocus.requestFocus();
                        _textyController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                            TextPosition(offset: _textyController.text.length));
                        for (var todo in data) {
                          print(
                              'Text: ${todo.text}, Completed: ${todo.checked}, Priority: ${todo.priority}, Key: ${todo.key}');
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: '+ Add a task',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      focusColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```